# My line.split function is not working as intended and I'm not sure why

Tags: python, list, loops, split, index-error

I'm trying to make a list with multiple lines, split in four, and have each of the four go into its own list, but whenever I try, I get an error of `num2` is an Index error list out of range. I'm not quite sure what my problem is. I was hoping someone could point it out.

Here is my code:

```
item = [
"Ham and Egg Sandwich $(15.75,10.0,44.0)",
"Bacon and Cheese Plate $(9.5,3.0,50.0)",
'Tuna Salad $(12.3,4.0,20.0)',
'Beef Soup $(9.0,2.0,30.0)',
'Spicy Beef Barbeque $(20.0,18.0,20.0)',
'Pork Barbeque $(18.0,12.0,35.0)',
'Oven Chicken Barbeque $(15.0,9.0,50.0)',
'Pulled Beef Barbeque Burger $(25.0,20.0,35.0)',
'House Salad $(5.0,2.5,46.0)',
'Pellegrino $(5.4,3.0,60.0)',
'White Wine $(7.5,5.0,40.0)',
'Red Wine $(11.0,4.0,71.0)'
 ]

for line in item:
   itemInfo = line.split("$")
   itemName = itemInfo[0].strip()
   resplit = itemInfo[1].strip()
   for line in resplit:
     split = line.split(",")
     num1 = split[0].strip()
     num2 = split[1].strip()
```

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: `resplit` is a string, so you're iterating through each character one by one. What is the intended behavior?

Comment: As said by @EricJin, ```resplit``` is a ```string```. So, when you do ```for line in respite:```, value stored in ```line``` during each iteration are individual characters from ```resplit```. So, ```len(split)``` is ```1```. Hence, ```split[1]``` is ```out of index```.

Comment: My intended output is to have itemName to store all the Names so everything from Ham and Egg Sandwich to Red wine. Then num1 to store the 1st set of numbers so the 15.75 through the 11.   num2 to store the 2nd set of numbers so the 10.0 through the 4.0.  num3 to store the 3rd set of numbers so the 44.0 through the 71.0. so an example out put would be itemName[0] = Ham and Egg Sandwich, num1[0]= 15.75, num2[0] = 10.0 and num3[0]=44.0

Comment: Please [edit] the question (and hopefully add more explanation) because the comment formatting is really hard to read.

Answer (score 0):

See the comments in line regarding the original code.

```
item = [
    "Ham and Egg Sandwich $(15.75,10.0,44.0)",
    "Bacon and Cheese Plate $(9.5,3.0,50.0)",
    'Tuna Salad $(12.3,4.0,20.0)',
    'Beef Soup $(9.0,2.0,30.0)',
    'Spicy Beef Barbeque $(20.0,18.0,20.0)',
    'Pork Barbeque $(18.0,12.0,35.0)',
    'Oven Chicken Barbeque $(15.0,9.0,50.0)',
    'Pulled Beef Barbeque Burger $(25.0,20.0,35.0)',
    'House Salad $(5.0,2.5,46.0)',
    'Pellegrino $(5.4,3.0,60.0)',
    'White Wine $(7.5,5.0,40.0)',
    'Red Wine $(11.0,4.0,71.0)'
]

for line in item:
     # line = an entry from the list
     # Example: "Ham and Egg Sandwich $(15.75,10.0,44.0)"
    itemInfo = line.split("$")
     # itemInfo  = list
     # Example ['Ham and Egg Sandwich ', '(15.75,10.0,44.0)']
    itemName = itemInfo[0].strip()
    # itemName = str Example: 'Ham and Egg Sandwich'
    resplit = itemInfo[1].strip()
     # resplit = str Example: '(15.75,10.0,44.0)'
    for line in resplit: # So line = str Example: '(' one character.
        split = line.split(",")
        num1 = split[0].strip() # Is one character '('
        num2 = split[1].strip() # Thus index error, no more characters.
```

Following code accomplishes the objective as I understand it.

```
item = [
    "Ham and Egg Sandwich $(15.75,10.0,44.0)",
    "Bacon and Cheese Plate $(9.5,3.0,50.0)",
    'Tuna Salad $(12.3,4.0,20.0)',
    'Beef Soup $(9.0,2.0,30.0)',
    'Spicy Beef Barbeque $(20.0,18.0,20.0)',
    'Pork Barbeque $(18.0,12.0,35.0)',
    'Oven Chicken Barbeque $(15.0,9.0,50.0)',
    'Pulled Beef Barbeque Burger $(25.0,20.0,35.0)',
    'House Salad $(5.0,2.5,46.0)',
    'Pellegrino $(5.4,3.0,60.0)',
    'White Wine $(7.5,5.0,40.0)',
    'Red Wine $(11.0,4.0,71.0)'
]

for line in item:
    # line = an entry from the list
    # Example: "Ham and Egg Sandwich $(15.75,10.0,44.0)"
    itemInfo = line.split("$")
    # itemInfo  = list
    # Example ['Ham and Egg Sandwich ', '(15.75,10.0,44.0)']
    itemName = itemInfo[0].strip()
    # itemName = str Example: 'Ham and Egg Sandwich'
    # itemInfo[1] = str Example: Example: '(15.75,10.0,44.0)'
    numbers = itemInfo[1][1:-1].split(',')  # Drop parentheses and split
    num1 = numbers[0]
    num2 = numbers[1]
    num3 = numbers[2]
    print(f'{itemName=}, {num1=},{num2=},{num3=}')
```

Output

```
itemName='Ham and Egg Sandwich', num1='15.75',num2='10.0',num3='44.0'
itemName='Bacon and Cheese Plate', num1='9.5',num2='3.0',num3='50.0'
itemName='Tuna Salad', num1='12.3',num2='4.0',num3='20.0'
itemName='Beef Soup', num1='9.0',num2='2.0',num3='30.0'
itemName='Spicy Beef Barbeque', num1='20.0',num2='18.0',num3='20.0'
itemName='Pork Barbeque', num1='18.0',num2='12.0',num3='35.0'
itemName='Oven Chicken Barbeque', num1='15.0',num2='9.0',num3='50.0'
itemName='Pulled Beef Barbeque Burger', num1='25.0',num2='20.0',num3='35.0'
itemName='House Salad', num1='5.0',num2='2.5',num3='46.0'
itemName='Pellegrino', num1='5.4',num2='3.0',num3='60.0'
itemName='White Wine', num1='7.5',num2='5.0',num3='40.0'
itemName='Red Wine', num1='11.0',num2='4.0',num3='71.0'
```

Comment: Let me know here in the comments if additional clarification is needed.  For instance slicing `numbers = itemInfo[1][1:-1]` etc.